# New series expansion formula?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, reference-request, summation, euler-maclaurin

> Let $f(x)$ be a continuous function that converges to $0$ and can be differentiated for an infinite amount of times. Then we have $$f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac{(-1)^kB_{2k}}{(2k)!}f^{(k+1)}(x)-f'(x+k)\right)-\frac{f'(x)}2$$ Where $B_k$ are the Bernoulli coefficients

The proof of this formula is straightforward. Take the derivative on both sides of the Euler-Maclaurin Summation formula and $$\sum_{k=1}^x f(k)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty(f(k)-f(k+x))$$ (which only works when $f(k)\sim0$), set the results equal to each other, and solve for $f(x)$. I am wondering if this formula has been discovered already, which I think it is because of its simple proof. If so, what is it called?

Edit: Since $f(x)$ is decreasing, this formula is pretty useless so it is possible that it isn't in the literature. I don't know for sure though.

Comment: This looks awfully familiar to [Ramanujan summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan_summation)!

Comment: How do you know that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty(f(k)-f(k+x))$ converge?

Comment: @jjagmath It telescopes.

Comment: Not every telescoping series converge

Comment: @jjagmath actually, in this case, assuming I'm right about this being a Ramanujan Summation, [this still provides a meaningful value to divergent summations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan_summation#Ramanujan_summation_of_divergent_series) (which is, in fact, its main usecase).

Comment: @jjagmath Actually? Since it equals a partial sum, which must converge. It works for $f(k)=\frac1k$

Comment: No, it doesn't converge in general. And just because it works for $1/k$ doesn't means that it happens I'm general.

Comment: @jjagmath $f(k)$ is decreasing by the way.

Comment: Yes, I read the hypothesis. Those are not sufficient.

Comment: @jjagmath I edited the OP. Maybe it works now?

Comment: @Graviton It looks similar but not quite equivalent. His summation works for all functions while mine is disabled.

Comment: Not related to your post, but are you still in 8th grade ?

Comment: @An_Elephant Yes :)

Comment: $\sum_{k=1}^m (f(k)-f(k+x)) = \sum_{k=1}^x f(k) -  \sum_{k=1}^x f(m+k)$. Taking the limit when $m\to \infty$ and assuming $f(k)\to c$ when $n\to \infty$ we get $\sum_{k=1}^\infty (f(k)-f(k+x)) = \sum_{k=1}^x f(k) -  x c$

Comment: Then, for your first equality to be true you need $f(k)\to 0$ when $k\to \infty$ (and nothing more).

Comment: @jjagmath Okay, thanks! I will edit :) That's what I meant to say but I was unclear.

Comment: How do you know that $f(x)$ decreases? (Not saying I know how to answer this question, because I don't ‍♂️.)

Comment: @Accelerator You mean how I know that $f(x)\rightarrow0$. This is because the second formula works only when that happens.

Comment: I am missing the part where you show that the infinite sum with the Bernoulli numbers converges to a finite real number.